# Changing Collation on MySql DB table COLUMN

Tags: php, mysql

Got this problem , `error #1283, column cannot be part of FULLTEXT index`. when changing collation from `latin_swedish`, to `utf8_general_ci`. Changed all manually but there are two columns on the Mysql table it is not changing but showing above error.
OK, I tried the PHP script to run, but truly again, where to execute it? is it to run from within the PHPmyadmin as the SQL query? or where? 
Help, please.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this a SQL error or PHP? Because if it's a PHP error, you can change the COLLATE depending on the type of connection you're setting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653076/mysql-error-column-columnname-cannot-be-part-of-fulltext-index

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if this is really Mysql error or PHP,  I think it is something in the column of the database that does not allow to be changed,, Please correct me if I am wrong, I imported the databases from Win 2003 Server to Ubuntu 14.04 Server using PhpMyAdmin so I think, it brought all the trouble I had and I did not know about it when running my websites on WIN 2003. Now, on Ubuntu server when I create new website with new database, the collation it is ok. It is utf8_general_ci in all tables and columns. 
Thank you for reading ,, any idea?
Please.

Comment: I tried using locally PhpMyAdmin alter the columns and it is not working, also I use Mysql work-bench giving me the same; error #1283, column cannot be part of FULLTEXT index, Any help? please